# Multiple jquery code works in every browser apart from Firefox 3.5

Tags: jquery, firefox3.5

I have 3 different jquery uses & put it into one code as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ticker01").liScroll({travelocity: 0.075}); 

    $(mainContent).corner("10px");

    $(".article .thebody").hide();
    $("#mainContent .article ul")
        .prepend("<li class='readbody'><a href='' title='Read the article'>Read/Hide Story</a></li>");

    $(".actions li.readbody a").click(function(event){
        $(this).parents("ul").prev(".thebody").slideToggle("normal");

        // Stop the link click from doing its normal thing
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

The first one controls a scrolling news ticker, the 2nd controls rounded corners and the 3rd controls a slideToggle function. All 3 also have seperate jquery files associated to them and are linked as follows: (put BEFORE the jquery part above in the . 1st one for slidetoggle, 2nd for news ticker, 3rd for corners)

```
<script src="../jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery.li-scroller.1.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../jquery/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In Safari & IE, all 3 work fine however in FF 3.5 only the news ticker seems to work. I can't seem to get all the working at the same time in FF & i have no idea why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is

```
$(mainContent).corner("10px");
```

supposed to be

```
$('#mainContent').corner("10px");
```

or that selector cached in a variable `mainContent`? The code you have posted looks ok in the context you have posted it, could you also provide the relevant HTML you are working with (ideally put a stripped version on [JSBin](http://jsbin.com) for answerers to play with).

Comment: Thank You so much. All 3 jquery functions now work at the same time. It was confusing at 1st because it worked fine on Safari & IE whereas i expected the complete opposite.

Comment: no problem. Different browsers handle undefined variables differently, and if I recall correctly, Firefox is quite unforgiving about it and so any code after the error will not execute. IE on the other hand, is really relaxed.

Comment: Oh by the way, if this solves your problem, please mark it as the "accepted" answer (click on the tick to the left of the post, underneath the vote counter).

Answer (score 0):

For debugging javascript in Firefox, [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) is your friend.